# How can I sort a category product loop by position with elastic search outside of category page?

Tags: magento2, product, category, sorting, elasticsearch

I am creating a **product** loop on the **homepage** of our site. The site has **smile elastic search** running. I have set up the **manual sort** for **products** in the **category admin** and can loop thru the products, but I am not able to **sort by position**.

```
<?php foreach ($category as $categoryId): ?>
<?php 

$category = $categoryFactory->create()->load($categoryId);
$categoryProducts = $category->getProductCollection()
                        ->addAttributeToSort('position','ASC')
                        ->addAttributeToSelect('*');

?>

<?php foreach ($categoryProducts as $product): ?>

    // do something with the products

<?php endforeach ?>
```

Comment: I am also facing the same situation..could you share the code to sort the product collection by position.

Comment: I ended up sorting outside of ES with Magento's built-in sorting. Magento Admin can't change this when ES is active. I set the sort position in the mysql table catalog_category_product.